# react-redux store not updating within onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm experiencing this weird issue where my react-redux store is updating, but is not updating within the function that calls the actions.

`this.props.active` is `undefined`, then I set it to an integer with `this.props.actions.activeSet(activeProc)`, but it remains `undefined` and enters the next if condition.

I know my app is working because everything else works with `this.props.active` having the correct value.

Is this supposed to happen?

**edit:**

After doing some testing, it appears that the state remains the same inside the onClick function.

All calls to `console.log(this.props)` made within the onClick function show no change to the state, but adding `setTimeout(() => {console.log(this.props)}, 1)` at the end to test shows that the state is being updated.

Other parts of the app are working as intended, with state changes applied immediately.

But I still don't understand what is going on.

**Component function code**

```
() => {
    console.log(this.props.active); // undefined
    if (this.props.active === undefined && this.props.readyQueue.length > 0) {
        let activeProc = this.props.readyQueue[0];
        this.props.actions.readyPop();
        this.props.actions.activeSet(activeProc); // set to an integer
        this.props.actions.execStateSet("Running");
    }

    console.log(this.props.active); // still remains undefined
    if (this.props.active === undefined) {
        this.props.actions.execStateSet("Idle");
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        active: state.ProcessReducer.active,
    };
}
```

**Action code**

```
export const activeSet = (procId) => {
    return {
        type: 'ACTIVE_SET',
        procId
    }
}
```

**Reducer code**

```
case 'ACTIVE_SET':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        active: action.procId
    });
```

Comment: are you sure that `active` property is tied to `props`, not some other object? - check `mapStateToProps()`

Comment: @ebramtharwat I edited my question to include mapStateToProps(). I think I have mapped it correctly.

Comment: console. log the state in reducer and see if its getting set correctly, you can also use redux extension for chrome to debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Redux state updates synchronously with the dispatch of your action. Your reducer has executed by the time the `dispatch` call returns.

However, React isn't Redux. Redux tells React-Redux's wrapper component that the state has changed. This also happens before `dispatch` returns.

React-Redux then tells React that the component needs to be rerendered by calling `forceUpdate`. React then waits until it feels it's a good time to take care of that. I haven't looked, but it probably uses `setImmediate` or equivalent but it's async. This allows React to batch updates and maybe there are other reasons.

In any case, the React-Redux wrapper component will get rendered by React when the time comes and it'll use your `mapStateToProps` to distill the`props` out of the state and then passes them to React as props for your actual component. Then, when React feels it's an okay time, it calls your `render` method or function. It may do all kinds of things in before that, such as calling `componentWillReceiveProps` or rendering some other component that also needs rendering. In any case it's  none of our business. React does its thing. But when your Render function is called, your props will now reflect the new state.

You shouldn't rely on new state in an `onClick` handler. The `onClick` should only call the bound action creator, which I guess is now more aptly called an action dispatcher. If something needs to be done with the new state, you should use Redux-Thunk middleware  and create a thunked action creator. These have access to `getState` and if they don't perform any internal async stuff, then the entire action can actually be just as synchronous as a simple dispatch (not that you'd need that in a simple `onClick` handler).

Finally, React is very asynchronous in nature. Think of it as telling React what you want (component + props) and letting React take it from there. If React needs to know how to turn a component into DOM elements, it'll call your component's `render` function. How or when React does is thing is an implementation detail that doesn't concern us.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not too sure if I need Redux-Thunk as I'm not trying to delay the function.

Comment: How would I go about using an onClick to run my function and make it work as expected?

Comment: Your function should be an action creator or a reducer. If it's a thunked action creator it can call getState and dispatch multiple actions. A reducer can manipulate the state at will. It's probably best to make a new Acton that does all the things you wanted to put in the onClick function.

Comment: Just to clarify, any logic that handles state manipulation should be done with actions and reducers; this logic should not be in component functions (which is what I did).

Comment: Thanks @DDS! I'll refactor my code into actions/reducers.